# AX ERROR when using Accessibility Inspector for iOS app.

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, accessibility

I'm testing an iPhone app with the simulator. Whenever I click on certain elements, I receive this error in console:

```
AX ERROR: Could not find my mock parent, most likely I am stale.
```

This error does not seem to cause any side-effects. I can use the app and examine the elements freely. Any idea what it may be caused by?

Comment: Does this app include and third party libraries or frameworks?

Comment: The problem involved Gorilla Logic's FoneMonkey library, which makes heavy use of accessibility labels.

Comment: Could this originate from the external library? Do a quick search for `AX ERROR` in the project files, and see if it returns anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/freerangecode/FRCTableViewDataSources/commit/8d6fbfe8520a94275dd1e1e175ee445e4e0f2b01

Change made to fix issue, you might need to pull changes and update your library.

Comment: I don't even know how you discovered this, but thank you. Extra credit points for answering a question from almost a year ago.

Comment: Not the problem for me, and probably not for most people who find this question either. I'm getting this warning without using any third party libraries; the warning is clearly being spat out from somewhere within the Cocoa Touch framework.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that the code path eventually called

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
[tableView endUpdates]
```

within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Removing the call got rid of these AX Error log messages as well as a bunch of other UI glitches.

Answer (score 0):

Cool!

I just have this strange error when using MJPopupBackgroundView. After checking its codes for a while, I noticed that, the author added a UITableView to another UIViewController's view as a sub view, but he didn't add the table's view controller to the other UIViewController as a child view controller.

So the solution is quite easy, after adding a sub view like this:

```
[parentViewController.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
```

You only need to add one more line like this:

```
[parentViewController addChildViewController:childViewController];
```

Voila!