# Custom tableview section header with storyboard and got error?

Tags: iphone, storyboard, uitableview

If I [add custom uitableView sectionheader using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396643/584254) I get this error `AX ERROR: Could not find my mock parent, most likely I am stale.` What does this error mean and how can I solve it? Header code:

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"sectionHeaderID";
    UITableViewCell *headerview = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    return headerview;
}
```

Comment: Please post your section header code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section header is not the same as table view cell. You should create your own UIView for the header view instead of taking it from table view cell. For example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 100.0)];
    return headerview;
}
```

Comment: Thanks actually I do so, I just want to custom headerView with storyboard, At last , I give up and use code to init header view

Answer (score 5):

Actually if you look at the comments in the post you linked pedro.m, gives a possible solution. He added a subview to the cell he calls contentView then returns it.

What I did was a bit simpler:

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"sectionHeaderID";
    UITableViewCell *headerview = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    return headerview.contentView;
}
```

This fixed the error for me.