# Possible to customize UITableView head in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add a button to headerView, is it possible from storyboard or only programmatically?

Comment: Create custom UIView as headerView and buttons in it..

Comment: please see tutorial i added..

Comment: duplicate of this, it designs view in storyboard, add it to a cell, and extract view from cell in `viewForHeaderInSection`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Create custom UIView as headerView and buttons in it..

try this blog [here](http://www.accella.net/custom-header-and-footer-views-for-uitableviews/)

Comment: Please make it as a comment not answer.