# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier keeps returning nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm basically trying to do what's in this link

> > [How to Implement Custom Table View Section Headers and Footers with Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard)

In my storyboard, I've embedded static cells in my TableViewController

I selected one of my table view cells and set the identifier as "CustomHeader" (at the storyboard)

and below is a snippet of my code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        var headerView:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeader") as? UITableViewCell

        if (headerView == nil){
            println("errrrrrr")
        }
        return headerView
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }
```

However, console keeps printing "errrrrrr" meaning that headerView is nil.

But I think whose identifier is "CustomHeader" cannot be nil because I manually selected a cell and set its identifier as CustomHeader in the storyboard!!

I'm new to iOS so I don't get what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To dequeue a cell from a storyboard, you need to use the method which takes an index path. That is, don't use:

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)
```

Instead, use:

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)
```

The hacky approach in the question you linked to no longer works. This method returns a header. Don't dequeue a cell.

You should use `registerNib(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)` or `registerClass(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)`, and `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(_:)`, as documented.

Comment: Thanks!! Without you telling me the approach in my link is no longer valid, I would have been wasting a lot of time!! I implemented in other way!