# How to set my view as my TableViewheader?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a view (with a searchbar and some buttons in it) to my UITableViewController. I've then created an outlet for the view in my ViewController.h file and synthasized it in my ViewController.m file.

Here's a screen shot of my current setup

[image]

I'm using

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

And I'm using

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return headerView;
}
```

But my view still scrolls up and down with the table, it doesn't seem to be set as the header properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it doesn't seem to be set as the header properly" -- yes it is being set properly. That is how a table header behaves. If you don't want it to scroll, then you can do one of two things. Either add the view as a sibling view to a UIViewController (your view above, with the table view below), or, if you only have one section, you can use it as a section header which will stick to the top.

Comment: How can I set it to the section header?

Comment: @Phil, you implement tableView:viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: @Phil, remove the line, self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView; I don't know if that is interfering with your implementation of viewForHeaderInSection. You also should implement heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: I removed that lined as suggested, but it's still scrolling up and down.

Comment: @Phil, that's because you added the view to the table view in the storyboard, which automatically makes it a table header view (even if you take out that line). You should make that view in a xib file (you can copy and paste it into one), and register that xib (
registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:). In viewForHeader InSection, you would then use 
dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier: to get your view. Be sure to implement tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: or the height will be 0.

Comment: I'll try that thanks, but aren't we all meant to just use storyboards now and not xib files?

Comment: @Phil, no, there's no reason not to still use xibs (along with storyboards).

Comment: Would it better to create the view and contents programmatically?

Comment: @Phil, that's up to you; do it however you want. I have seen people do it in the storyboard, using a cell prototype to make their header view -- see the accepted answer here (I don't know if this is the right way to go) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard

Comment: I've tried to follow the .nib approach, but I've run into an error as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965363/invalid-nib-registered-for-identifier