# prolonged tap on tableView header cell crashes the App

Tags: uitableview

I don't know whats happening but when I prolong my tap on a table view header cell the app crashes with Bad Excess Error. I am not registering any tapGestures in the viewController or in my custom tableViewCell class.

This is my code for my header cell

```
    CustomTableViewCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headerCell"];
    UIView *view = cell.contentView;
    return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of research found this little hack.

```
    while (cell.contentView.gestureRecognizers.count) {
        [cell.contentView removeGestureRecognizer:[cell.contentView.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
```

[How to Implement Custom Table View Section Headers and Footers with Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard/24044628#24044628)