# separate segue on section header as on table view row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, sections

I have a tableview setup whereby every row has its own custom section header. This is done with a prototype cell in the story board. I have a segue to a view controller on the click event of a row. I achieved this by ctrl dragging on the storyboard.

I want my section header to segue to a different controller, however. I ctrl dragged from my header prototype cell to a view controller on the storyboard also.

The result is that both clicking on the row and clicking on the header of the row are bringing me to the same view controller.

It seems the header is linked to the row. Is there any way around this? Could I give my segues identifiers and override the prepare for seg? Or is it possible to have a separate click event on a section header as the rest of the row?

**UPDATE:**
I have to tried to implement it as follows:

I ctrl dragged from my vc to the destination vc in the storyboard and gave the seg an identifier.

In my viewForHeaderInSection, I have added the following:

```
let tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("seg"))
tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = false
headerCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapper)
return headerCell
```

my seg func just perform a seg with the identifier I set up as explained above.

```
func seg(){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("feedToMembersDetailed", sender: self)
}
```

In my overridePrepareForSeg, I check the identifier and call the appropriate method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "feedToMembersDetailed"){
            //getting in here
            getMembersContentFromRow(segue)
        }
        ... extra conditions
    }
```

and finally my getMembersContentFromRow looks as follows:

```
func getMembersContentFromRow(segue : UIStoryboardSegue){
        var membersDetailed = segue.destinationViewController as! MembersDetailedController
        if let indexPath = self.feedTableView.**indexPathForSelectedRow()**{
            if let selectedId = self.newsFeed?[indexPath.section].authorId{
                Prefs.followedId = selectedId.toInt()!
            }
            println("setting postAuthorPic as \(self.newsFeed?[indexPath.section].authorPic)")
            membersDetailed.postAuthorPic = self.newsFeed?[indexPath.section].authorPic
            membersDetailed.postAuthorID = self.newsFeed?[indexPath.section].authorId
            membersDetailed.postAuthor = self.newsFeed?[indexPath.section].author

        }
        else{
            //getting in here. I need a method that can retrieve indexPath for me
            println("could not get selected row")
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the result after update?

Comment: @iRealMe see my comment in the final else? I am getting into that condition "could not get selected row" I need some way of getting the indexPath in my getMembersContentFromRow func

Comment: Because, you have performed tap gesture manually. Its not considering it as selectedRow I guess

Comment: And you are trying to get index of header cell right?

Comment: @iRealMe Yeah but I'm wondering how can I get it from that point?

Comment: @iRealMe well every cell has it's own header. I just need to get the indexPath.section var

Comment: See [this example](https://medium.com/@MichaelVoznesensky/fully-interactive-ios-section-headers-in-swift-47a5d8c30386) It is something similar you need I guess

Comment: BTW, in viewForHeaderInSection , section is alreay there as parameter

Comment: @iRealMe and how can I pass that as a param into my seg function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here it is, I am not writing code, just the steps you need to follow

1. Remove the segues you have created from your row and headers. Just assign SegueIdentifier for the controllers to be opened, say **SegueIdentifierForRow** and **SegueIdentifierForSection**.
2. Since there is no action in tableview headers, you need to add a custom action may be an `UIButton` or, `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Cell selection you can leave as it is. And to determine section selection you can set `tag` for each section.
3. On Row CellSelection manually initialise ViewController by using identifier **SegueIdentifierForRow**, and same for section using different identifier **SegueIdentifierForSection**.

Follow above you should be able to do whats required.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement `viewForHeaderInSection:` method and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a view which would be retuned as header view. You can then handle the tap on your table section headers to go to different View Controller.

Comment: since the header is already seguing to the place that my rows are set up to segue to, will i also have to implement an override shouldPerformSegue func too?

Comment: Why are you not ctrl+drag your section header segue to the VC you want to load on tap on section header?

Comment: this is what I tried first as per the question...but the segue that is linked to my row...is triggering when i click on a section header... for some reason. I'm new to iOS dev, this is why I was unsure if this was the expected behaviour of a row's section header

Comment: See, unlike table rows, section headers are not tappable by default. You to enable them to take user taps. One programmatic way I told you how to go about it. There is another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard) which explains about it the storyboard way. Take a look!

Comment: but by default when I click on my section header right now, I am getting the segue that is linked to the row. I have added two ctrl drag segues one for the row nad one for the header. Then in overrideprepareforseg, I am checking the segue.identifier and seguing then based on that, but when I click on a section header, i am getting the wrong identifier i.e. the one linked to my row..