# How to register a UIView to be reused for UITable view header without using nib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a UIView on my storyboard and I want to use this view for the header of my UITableView. I have gave an identifier on storyboard for this view and in viewForHeaderInSection class I dequeue this identifier as shown below. However, whenever I reload the table and I found the headerCell is a new instance. It is not reused in this case.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! UserHomeHeaderCell
```

I have tried to register this class on viewDidLoad() method as below:

```
tableView.registerClass(UserHomeHeaderCell.classForCoder, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
```

But all the cell's content which are linked with storyboard are nil. How should I reuse this header?

Comment: I think your best option is to move the header view into it's own separate .xib file and load it from there.

Comment: Another approach is mentioned in the below link.
[SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard)
The key is 'use a prototype cell as your section header and / or footer.'
but this is a hack with prototype cells. Best approach is to use a Nib.

Comment: http://samwize.com/2015/11/06/guide-to-customizing-uitableview-section-header-footer/ refer this link.. it uses reusable header view..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to register nib in the ViewDidLoad()

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UserHomeHeaderCell" , bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: HeaderCell)
```

Comment: I don't have nib file. The view was created in my storyboard

Comment: instead of registering class in ViewDidLoad try the code in the method iteself

Comment: Do you mean try the code in viewForHeaderInSection method? I already tried but still the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! UserHomeHeaderCell
    return headerCell.contentView
}
```