# How do I add a separator line for a custom UITableView header section nib?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I followed the instructions from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582046/3649364) and managed to get my custom UITableView header section like so:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableSectionHeader", bundle: nil)
    billTableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "TableSectionHeader")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = billTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "TableSectionHeader")
    let header = cell as! TableSectionHeader
    header.lblPerson.text = array[section].name
    header.lblTotal.text = "$0.00"
    return cell
}
```

Everything works fine however I need a separator line for the sections and because the section is a UIView from my nib, I'm not able to use the `.separatorStyle`...

[image]

I need to add a separator line because I want to expand/collapse the rows. Much thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add a seperator yourself like this :

```
CGRect seperatorFrame = CGRectMake(0, headerView.frame.size.height-1, tableView.bounds.size.width, 1);
UIView *seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:seperatorFrame];
seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[headerView addSubview:seperatorView];
```

or use Autolayout in .xib:

[image: xib autolayout]

Comment: Hmm, it works, but only when I scroll it up and down, not when inserting sections. I put your code in the `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate. Where should I put this code so that when inserting sections the separator is also added?

Comment: If you are using xib, you can try dragging a UIView(seperatorView) and configuring AutoLayout.

Comment: Yes, I am using xib. I'm not sure what it means by configuring autolayout.. Could you explain? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, nvm. I got what you mean. I just added another UIView, changed its height and added constraints. With a little tweaking it looks perfect now :) Thanks!

Comment: @iamhx Yes, that's what I mean