# Cannot see buttons on UITableView header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstableviewheader

I follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219234/how-to-implement-custom-table-view-section-headers-and-footers-with-storyboard) to add UITableView header, just create a View which include two buttons, however, cannot see two buttons when I run the app.

two overriden functions are:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 60.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *vw = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];

    return vw;
}
```

a screenshot attached:
[image]

Note: the target ios: 11.4, xcode is 9.4.1, objective-c

=========================================
rest code of ViewController.m

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    if (self) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{    
}

- (IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender
{
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    BNRItem *item = [BNRItemStore sharedStore].allItems[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = item.description;

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    //[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [BNRItemStore sharedStore].allItems.count;
}
```

Comment: Did you add your custom header cell class ? I can't see any file name HeaderCell in this pic.

Comment: There is a cell with the identifier `HeaderCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *vw = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];

    return vw;
}
```

Write this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewCell *vw = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];

    return vw;
}
```

> dequeuResuableCellWithIdentifier returns a UITableViewCell as per the documentation:
>
> @available(iOS 6.0, *)
>
> open func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Comment: thanks @iPeter, regardless change or not, the vw returned is nil.

Comment: So your `heightForHeader` and `viewForHeader` is getting called?

Comment: yes, both are called, I set breakpoint inside, and both are hit. and I also override both cellforrow and numberofrows

Comment: Why did you comment out the code where you registering the HeaderCell  to your `tableView`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174778/discussion-between-ipeter-and-james-hao).

Comment: Hi @iPeter are you there? I am in the room now

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the previous comment. You can try following

```
UITableViewCell * vw =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];
    }
```

And check the value in vw.

Comment: not work, I suspect it is a xcode 9.4.1 bug, I tried many ways, and cannot make it work.

Comment: You have to return vw.contentView.